# No search terms can be added on facebook.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, search, facebook

When landing on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook* (http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ redirects to this URL) the search bar at the top is pre populated with

```
[facebook] or [facebook-graph-api] or [facebook-like] or [facebook-javascript-sdk] or [facebook-fql] or [facebook-php-sdk] or [facebook-c#-sdk] or [facebook-opengraph] or [facebook-apps] or [facebook-ios-sdk] or [facebook-android-sdk] or [facebook-login] or [facebook-page] or [facebook-comments] or [facebook-social-plugins] or [facebook-oauth] or [facebook-access-token] or [facebook-authentication] or [facebook-iframe] or [facebook-canvas]
```

and no further search terms can be added. :-(

[image]

Comment: By "does not work", you mean what exactly? Your last sentence? Asking because I am getting results.

Comment: @Oded I think what OP means is that the *related tags* list is empty.

Comment: @Stijn - possibly. I'd like the OP to confirm (or deny). As it stands, this bug report is overly vague to be acted on.

Comment: The `maxlength` attribute of the search box is set to 240, but that query is 443 characters long. That's why you cannot enter more. You have to remove enough characters to go back below the 240 limit before you can enter something.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi so why is this pre populated with an ivalid value?

Comment: So, the question is - why do you need to use **all** of those tags? Consider limiting the search to a smaller set of tags.

Comment: @powtac - because that is what `facebook*` expands to.

Comment: @powtac, that's not invalid, just too long. Maybe we should delete some of these `[facebook*]` tags. Or maybe most of them.

Comment: @Oded SO offered me those Facebook related tags and I want to search trough all Facebook related questions...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ok, currently it behaves not as expected and feels a little buggy.

Comment: What happens when you put `searchterm facebook*`?

Comment: @Oded why does `[facebook*]` does not expand to `[facebook*] is:question`? This would not added the whole facebook-tags to the search box and it would allow to add additional search terms

Comment: @Jehof - I don't know the reasoning behind the way expansion works. And people may be looking for answers, not questions.

Comment: @Oded This question is about an UX problem, the question you refer to is about a the technical(?) problem.